# how to know if the page i am on is a node or not

Tags: 8, nodes

with a custom module, in drupal 8, how can I test whether I am on a node entity or not, when i browse to that page?

If I do this  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');  I get an error if i'm not on a node.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? By limiting your module to nodes, you eliminate it from being usable on other entity types - which may be ok, but there may be a better way to go about it

Comment: I need to get a taxonomy term which will only be available to nodes.  I already know how to get the taxonomy term if i'm on a node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the route parameter is not a problem, this returns NULL if the route parameter is not present. But you have to check the node is not NULL, before using it:

```
if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
  $value = $node->field_name->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical'){
 //Do what you want.
}
```